# Use of need in "He needed all the help he could get...)

Tags: meaning, construction

> Peter **needed all the help he could get from** James and Sirius.

This construction seems odd.
I usually hear "he got all the help he needed".
But here it is opposite.
What does it exactly mean?
Is this construction common?

Answer (score 4):

Peter could not do [whatever it was] without help. In fact, it was so difficult that he needed *all* the help that the others were able to give him.

It's quite a common expression.

Answer (score 2):

Your second sentence, *He got all the help he needed.* describes what happened.

*He needed all the help he could get.* describes what he needed.

If he needed help, then what happened? Here are two possibilities:

1 He got all the help he needed.

2 He did not get all the help he needed.